# Can I track my lost Samsung galaxy ace

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-ace, lost-phone, gps-tracking, samsung-galaxy-ace-2

just over a week ago I lost my Samsung galaxy ace, it has a sim in it and i have the device's imei number, it won't be charged and have tried looking for it , I didn't have any tracking apps installed on it and I am getting stressed. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you have screen lock? Had you logged in into your google account on the phone?

Comment: I had a screen lock and password and I think i was logged on with google, I had a youtube app linked to my gmail

Comment: Have you tried Android Device Manager? Log into Google with account on the phone and go to https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager

Comment: thank you , will have to try , but how will that locate my phone ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have added your google account on it. then you can use below link to find it.

> https://security.google.com/settings/intro/security/find-your-phone?continue=https://myaccount.google.com/?utm_source%3DOGB&utm_source=OGB